# Change CSS for embedded youtube videos

Tags: css, margin, embedded-resource

Here's my site: http://oldtimesdaily.tumblr.com/

I am using tumblr right now where I post pictures and videos. Unfortunately, using the "Photo" and "Video" option won't allow me to put any title, so I use the "Text" option instead and simply embedd the pictures and videos.

The problem right now is that the embedded youtube videos aren't lined up with the pictures. My Pictures where I've put the 50px left margin are lined up perfectly, but how do I do the same to the youtube videos? Here's the CSS code:

.Post {

```
        /*    background: url('http://s23.postimg.org/5fvqrgozv/Post2.png') repeat-y center top; */
             background-color: white;     

            width:1000px; /* editable */ 
            margin: 0px 0px 0px; /* test*/
            line-height: 1.4; 
            }

            .Post img {

                margin: 0px 50px 50px 70px;  /* editable */         
                max-width: 100%;
                -webkit-box-shadow: #444 0px 0px 6px;
                -moz-box-shadow:    #444 0px 0px 6px;
                {block:PermalinkPage} 
                  width: 625px;
                {/block:PermalinkPage} /*editable
```

And the {block:Post}
{block:Posts}

```
            {block:Text}
              {block:IndexPage}

             <div id="postlinks">
             <div class="fb-like" data-href="{ShortURL}" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial">

              </div>
              </div>
              {/block:IndexPage}

               <div class="Text">
                {block:Title}
                <a href="{Permalink}" target="_blank" class="Title">{Title}</a> 

                {/block:Title}

                <div class="PostBody">{Body}</div>
            </div>


            {/block:Text}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the iframe-tag to the css rule for the img like this:

```
.Post img, iframe {

            margin: 0px 50px 50px 70px;  /* editable */         
            max-width: 100%;
            -webkit-box-shadow: #444 0px 0px 6px;
            -moz-box-shadow:    #444 0px 0px 6px;
            {block:PermalinkPage} 
              width: 625px;
            {/block:PermalinkPage} /*editable
```

Example shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZacV.png

Comment: That worked, thanks! However it also affected my other iframes. Is there a way to only specify iframes from youtube? Cause I have other iframes from facebook and a submit form for jotform as well that are being affected.

Comment: it looks like that all youtube iframes are having:
id="player1" or name="player1"